# Proving a simple statement about right angles and tangents

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, irrational-numbers

In [this blog post](http://www.thebigquestions.com/2016/10/28/breaking-the-language-barrier), Steve Landsburg presents a truly remarkable proof that the square root of 2 is irrational:

[image: 1]

In the comment section of that blog post, I tried to translate the proof into the system of Euclid's Elements.  I succeeded, except for one small step.

So my question is, how can we prove that the line containing the red line segment intersects the interior of lower leg of the right triangle?  I think it would be fairly easy to prove that the line containing the red segment intersects the line containing the lower leg somewhere.  (We just need f show that they're not parallel.) But how can we prove that the intersection point specifically lies somewhere on the lower leg?

Preferably I would like a proof that works within Euclid's Elements, which you can see [here](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/java/elements/elements.html).

EDIT: To be clear, the fact that the line intersects the lower leg is shown in the above picture, but I want a rigorous proof that doesn't depend on looking at a picture.

Comment: What is the definition of the red line segment? Is it defined as where the radius from one side of the 1X1 (by root 2) triangle intersects the circle? If so how does one know that point exists using Euclid, and then it would be another thing as you say to show it meets the lower segment of the right triangle.

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, it is the intersection point of the circle and the hypotenuse.  And the fact that the intersection point exists follows from Euclid's Proposition 1.3: http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/bookI.html

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: Label figure $\triangle ABC$, with "top" vertex $A$ and right angle at $C$; let circle meet hyp at $D$; let perp at $D$ meet the possibly-extended (but provably non-parallel) leg, $\overline{BC}$, at $E$. Since "|hyp| > |leg|", $D$ is interior to $\overline{AB}$. Drop a perp from $C$ to $F$ on hyp; since "|hyp| > |leg|", $F$ is interior to $\overline{AD}$, so $D$ is interior to $\overline{BF}$. Now, $\triangle BCF \sim \triangle BED$, so that $BF/BD = BC/BE$, so $BD < BF$ implies $BE < BC$. ([Bk V, Prop 14](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookV/propV14.html))

Comment: @Blue First of all, why does the fact that [hyp]>[leg] imply that F is in the interior of line segment AD?  Second of all, does your proof assume that E is to the right of C?  Because there's also the possibility that E is to the left of C.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: (1) "hyp > leg" implies $AC > AF$; but $AC = AD$, so $AD > AF$. ... (2) There certainly is the possibility that $E$ lies to the left of $C$. (That's why I mentioned that $\overline{BC}$ might need to be extended.) But, *wherever $E$ is*, we get those similar triangles (by Angle-Angle Similarity), which imply the proportion, which implies $\overline{BE}$ is too short for $E$ to be left of $C$. (BTW: It's also important that $E$ lies to the left of $B$. But the Parallel Postulate guarantees that *lines* $DE$ & $BC$ meet on the same side of $AB$ as $\angle ABC$, so we're okay.)

Answer (score 0):

There are three places where it could land. If it lands on that vertical edge, the line could be extended and it would land on a point on circle. It could land on that right angle vertice, which is also a point on circle. And by your "line containing red line" is a tangent. It can touch circle at only one point. The remaining third place is lower leg

Edit: assume the tangent meets the vertical edge, all the points on vertical edge are within the circle. A line from a point on the circle meeting a point within the circle, touches circle at another point ( i don't know again if it should be proved). So the tangent can't intersect with vertical line. The vertical line intersects at only one point on circle, the tangent could intersect this point, but then it would not be tangent. The tangent has to intersect the horizontal line. The length of red line and lower leg( just a name) should be equal(congruency of triangle, I don't know if I can use this), so it has to be lower leg, else the red line will be bigger than hypotenuse of small right angled triangle. I don't know what looking at picture means, hope this helps

Comment: First of all, how would you prove that if it intersects the vertical leg then it intersects the circle?  And how would you prove that it can't intersect the left or the right of the horizontal leg?

Comment: I am sorry but what is the red line?

Comment: It's the tangent line to the circle at the point where the circle intersects the hypotenuse of the right triangle.

Comment: To be clear, from the picture it's obvious that the red line does intersect the lower leg, but I want a rigorous proof that doesn't depend on looking at that picture.